# How to converts the input values ​according to the format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

**This is an example of my code.**

```
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    
    img_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Project/validation/Cclass/C003.jpg'
    img2 = image.load_img('/content/drive/My Drive/Project/validation/Cclass/C003.jpg')
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    preds = model.predict(x)
    
    
    p = []
    for val in preds[0]:
      p.append(round(val, 3))
    i, = np.where(np.isclose(p, max(p)))[0]
```

**And I get an error like this, what should I do?**

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 25088 but received input with shape [None, 224, 224, 3]
```

**Where the primary input I defined as**

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim=7 * 7 * 512))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input_dim is defined as a single number. 7x7x512 is exactly 25088 from the error message. Try defining input_dim=(224, 224, 3)

Comment: When I change as you say I get an error like this and my code.